# requirejs : concatenate into a single file with multiples asp.net pages and different require calls on each page

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I have one single concatenate minified main.min.js on a asp.net website. But some pages need to call some module, eg SpecializedMod.js. This module has been concatenated into main.min.js, but on a page where I call:

require(['path/SpecialzedMod'], function (SpecializedMod) {...}));

the SpecializedMod is not get from main.min.js but a new HTTP request calls SpecializedMod.js.
Is there a way to prevent it ?

Thanx.

Comment: Is there a reason the specialized module can't be included in the main js?

Comment: yes this specialized module has been concatenated and minified into main.min.js, that's why I would think require would have checked in main.min.js to see if this module was already there to prevent a second HTTP request just for this specialized module already there in main.min.js.